# iOS dev - UINavigationController: send data backwards to 2nd parent view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

so, I need to send data backwards when poping two views. I tried using protocol, so this is part of my code:

*RootViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@class SecondViewController;

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <PassInt>

@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *secondViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ThirdViewController *thirdViewController;
@property (nonatomic) int intNumber;

@end
```

*RootViewController.m*

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize secondViewController = _secondViewController;
@synthesize thirdViewController = _thirdViewController;
@synthesize intNumber = _intNumber;

- (void)setIntNumber:(int)number{
    _intNumber = number;
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if(!_thirdViewController){
        _thirdViewController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    if(!_secondViewController){
        _secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.secondViewController.thirdViewController = self.thirdViewController;
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondViewController animated:YES];
    }

@end
```

*SecondViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ThirdViewController;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) ThirdViewController *thirdViewController;

@end
```

*SecondViewController.m*

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize thirdViewController = _thirdViewController;

...

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.userPreferencesViewController animated:YES];
}
@end
```

*ThirdViewController.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PassInt <NSObject>
@required
- (void) setIntNumber:(int)number;
@end

@interface ThirdViewController : UIViewController{
id <PassInt> delegate;
}
@property (retain) id delegate;
- (IBAction)saveChanges;

@end
```

*ThirdViewController.m*

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@implementation ThirdViewController

- (IBAction)saveChanges{
    int someInt = 3;
    [[self delegate] setIntNumber:someInt];
    UINavigationController *tempNavigationController = self.navigationController;
    [tempNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [tempNavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
...
@end
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: can you describe more what you are trying to achieve. Because there is at least 4 ways I can think of, but choosing one will depend of your goal. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on someInt from ThirdViewController I call different secondViewControllers from rootViewController, so I need to pass that int from thirdViewController backwards to rootViewController. This solution is not working, I don't know why. I found examples only when sending backwards to first parent.

Comment: In ThirdViewController it is setIntNumber instead of setSymbolSize

Answer (score 0):

In the [UINavigationController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) check the property call :

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

> **Discussion**
>   The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

That could give you a handle to the rootViewController.
Would that be a good solution for you?
There is other ways. But from your comment I think that could be a match.

---

`[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0].someProerty;`

Comment: So from that array I can get pointer to instance of my rootViewController and just use rootViewController.intNumber = someInt ???? If I can do that then this is great solution!

Comment: @ClarkKent That should work. I've never used it like that, because I try to design in a way that I don't need to do it like that. But to reach the rootViewController that look an acceptable way. But to reach the 3rd ViewController from a hierarchy that have 5 ViewController I would strongly suggest to do it an other way that would be more generic and reusable. But for the root it is reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Another method could be to use NSNotifications.  Have the RootViewController resgister as an observer for a notification posted by the ThirdViewController.  Then in the userInfo dictionary of the notification posted by the ThirdViewController, you pass someInt as an NSNumber.

This provides sufficient abstraction because your ThirdViewController doesn't need to know what kind of object requires the information, it is just posting it so interested observers know about it.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You're never assigning anything to the delegate member of your ThirdViewController in the code you posted. Also, delegates should usually be assign, not retain.